# cannot find symbol error java invalidinputexception

Tags: java, switch-statement

```
public void processString(String input) throws InvalidInputException {//processes the string to check if the characters correct and what method it should go to
    for (char x : input.toCharArray()) {//for loop which checks each char
        switch (x) {

        case 'L' :  turnLeft();
                    break;
        case 'R' :  turnRight();
                    break;
        case 'M' :  moveRover();
                    break;

        default :   throw new InvalidInputException("Invalid signal");

        }
    }
}
```

I have this code however i am getting a cannot find symbol error
what am i doing wrong?

I get this error message

```
    public void processString(String input) throws InvalidInputException {//processes the string to check if the characters correct and what method it should go to
                                                   ^
  symbol:   class InvalidInputException
  location: class marsRover
marsRover.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
            default :   throw new InvalidInputException("Invalid signal");
                                  ^
  symbol:   class InvalidInputException
  location: class marsRover
2 errors
```

Comment: Have you imported `InvalidInputException` ?

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Comment: Is `InvalidInputException` in the classpath ? Have you imported it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the java compiler does not know which `InvalidInputException` class you are referring to.  There are two possibilities:

- You have not declared the `InvalidInputException` class.  If you intended to declare it yourself, it should be a subclass of `Exception` or some subclass of `Exception`.  The way that you are using it implies that it must (at least) have a constructor that takes a message as its argument.
- The `InvalidInputException` class has been declared in a different package, and you have not `import`-ed the class (or the package).  (If the class was declared in the same package as your `marsRover` class, you wouldn't need to import it ...)

We can dismiss the third possibility ... that you have imported the class, but it is not on the classpath ... because that would have given a compilation error message for the `import` statement!

---

While I have your attention, it looks like you have used `marsRover` as a classname.  That is a Java style violation.  Java class names should be "camel case" starting with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

Import InvalidInputException in your code